# Creating a new DataFrame out of 2 existing Dataframes with Values coming from Dataframe 1?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have 2 DataFrames.

DF1:

```
movieId title   genres
0   1   Toy Story (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
1   2   Jumanji (1995)  Adventure|Children|Fantasy
2   3   Grumpier Old Men (1995) Comedy|Romance
3   4   Waiting to Exhale (1995)    Comedy|Drama|Romance
4   5   Father of the Bride Part II (1995)  Comedy
```

DF2:

```
userId  movieId rating  timestamp
0   1   1   4.0 964982703
1   1   3   4.0 964981247
2   1   6   4.0 964982224
3   1   47  5.0 964983815
4   1   50  5.0 964982931
```

My new DataFrame should look like this.

DF_new:

```
userID Toy Story Jumanji Grumpier Old Men Waiting to Exhale Father of the Pride Part II
1       4.0
2
3
4
```

The Values will be the ratings of the the indiviudel user to each movie.
The movie titles are now the columns.
The userId are now the rows.

I think it will work over concatinating via the movieid. But im not sure how to do this exactly, so that i still have the movie names attached to the movieid.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: I can't understand your DF_new. The title row clumped together.

Comment: In DF_New the titles are the columns. And the values should be the ratings from each user.

Comment: If a movie never receives ratings, should it be contained in the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem consists of essentially 2 parts:

1. How to transpose `df2`, the sole table where user ratings comes from, to the desired format. [pd.DataFrame.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) is the standard way to go.
2. The rest is about mapping the `movieID`s to their names. This can be easily done by direct substitution on `df.columns`.

In addition, if movies receiving no ratings were to be listed as well, just insert the missing `movieID`s directly before name substitution mentioned previously.

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "movieId": [1,2,3,4,5],
        "title": ["toy story (1995)",
                  "Jumanji (1995)",
                  "Grumpier 33 (1995)",  # shortened for printing
                  "Waiting 44 (1995)",
                  "Father 55 (1995)"],

    }
)
# to better demonstrate the correctness, 2 distinct user ids were used.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "userId": [1,1,1,2,2],
        "movieId": [1,2,2,3,5],
        "rating": [4,5,4,5,4]
    }
)

# 1. Produce the main table
df_new = df2.pivot_table(index=["userId"], columns=["movieId"], values="rating")

print(df_new)  # already pretty close
Out[17]: 
movieId    1    2    3    5
userId                     
1        4.0  4.5  NaN  NaN
2        NaN  NaN  5.0  4.0


# 2. map movie ID's to titles

# name lookup dataset
df_names = df1[["movieId", "title"]].set_index("movieId")

# strip the last 7 characters containing year
# (assume consistent formatting in df1)
df_names["title"] = df_names["title"].apply(lambda s: s[:-7])

# (optional) fill unrated columns and sort
for movie_id in df_names.index.values:
    if movie_id not in df_new.columns.values:
        df_new[movie_id] = np.nan
else:
    df_new = df_new[df_names.index.values]

# replace IDs with titles
df_new.columns = df_names.loc[df_new.columns, "title"].values
```

### Result

```
df_new
Out[16]: 
        toy story  Jumanji  Grumpier 33  Waiting 44  Father 55
userId                                                        
1             4.0      4.5          NaN         NaN        NaN
2             NaN      NaN          5.0         NaN        4.0
```

Comment: Thx Bill. The pivot function was the missing thought. For the misssing values i used median values. Thx a lot.